# Python - Read CSV as List of Strings

Tags: python

I have a CSV file with only one column. Each row has some words inside.

```
Hello World1
Hello World2
Hello World3
```

Now I want to read this file as a list of strings, each row is an item inside the list. Like this:

```
['Hello World1', 'Hello World2', 'Hello World3']
```

I have tried below code:

```
with open("myFile.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)
```

But it gave me another square brackets inside for each element. How can I remove it?

```
[['Hello World1'], ['Hello World2'], ['Hello World3']]
```

Comment: you probably want to use `f.readlines()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**
This should solve your use case:

```
with open('myFile.csv') as file:
    data = file.read().splitlines()
```

**INPUT DATA:**

```
Hello World1
Hello World2
Hello World3
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['Hello World1', 'Hello World2', 'Hello World3']
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a simple text file, you can simply do

```
with open("myFile.csv") as f:
    data=[line for line in f]
```